# How to 'press' the close button in order to close navigation bar

Tags: angular

I am using angular 7.3.9 to build the solution.

I just want to know how to 'press' the button (programmatical) to 'close' the navigator bar?

or

How to hide (visible=false) the navigator bar?

*** Because I using window.open to open a new URL, navigation bar can be hidden is better.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this. Presuming that you have already created the sidenav component.

1. `header.component.html`

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <mat-toolbar-row>
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="_sidenav.toggle()">
            <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
        </button>
    </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
```

2. Add a sidenav service in your `header.component.ts`

```
import { SidenavService } from 'path/to/sidenav.service'
constructor(public _sidenav: SidenavService){}
```

3. The `sidenav.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSidenav } from '@angular/material/sidenav';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SidenavService {

  private _sidenav: MatSidenav

  constructor() { }

  setSidenav(sidenav: MatSidenav) {
    this._sidenav = sidenav;
  }

  toggle(): void {
    this._sidenav.toggle()
  }
  open() {
    return this._sidenav.open()
  }
  close() {
    return this._sidenav.close();
  }

}
```

4. **Don't forget to add the service in providers list in your root module**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [.....],
  imports: [
    ....
    ....
  ],
  providers: [SidenavService,....]
})
```